# How to use HibernateTemplate?

Tags: spring, hibernate

I am performing retrieval operation to get list of students from database. But I am getting 'empty' data from database. Used HibernateTemplate in 
Spring with Hibernate integration,

**domain class:-**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="student")
public class StdBO {
@Id
private int sno;
private String sname,sadd;
//setters and getters
}
```

How can I use HibernateCallBack() interface for search operation? This is my first time that integrating spring with hibernate, is the below way correct? I tried many ways to perform search operations using HibernateTemplate but failing to get the details

**DAO**

```
@Repository
public class StdDAO {
private HibernateTemplate ht;
public void setHt(HibernateTemplate ht) {
    this.ht = ht;
}
public List<StdBO> select(){

    List<StdBO> list = ht.executeFind(new HibernateCallback() {
        public Object doInHibernate(Session ses)
                throws HibernateException, SQLException {

            Criteria criteria=ses.createCriteria(StdBO.class);

            System.out.println("before printing sutdents");
            List<StdBO> bos = criteria.list();
            System.out.println("students are"+bos);//here getting empty list
            return bos;
        }

    });

    return list;
}
```

**xml**

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>com.nt.dao.StdDAO</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="template" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="dao" class="com.nt.dao.StdDAO">
    <property name="ht" ref="template" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need begin (and commit) a transaction to query data. You can do it manually by `session.beginTransaction()` or using `@Transactional` annotation. For using `@Transactional` annotation you will need to do some additional spring configuration:
[Hibernate Transaction Annotation Configuration](http://www.springbyexample.org/examples/hibernate-transaction-annotation-config.html).